# Make an array of random integers based on seed in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random, int, random-seed

I need to create an array of integers (doubles and floats are fine too but I don't think there is a difference) since I will need to do certain math actions with them such as * and +. I am trying to fill up the array with Random seeds (i.e. 1337 5443, I need to use these) but I can't convert a random variable into a int and I can't add or multiply random variables. So essentially I need to make an array of random numbers from specific seeds and I also need to be able to do math actions with each element of the list.
Here is an example of what I have done so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class{
public static int a [] = new int [101];
public static void main(String[] Args){
    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
        Random ran1 = new Random(1337);
        a [i] =  ran1;//THIS IS THE PROBLEM (incompatible types)
    }
    int sum = a[5] + a[8] * a[10];//this won't acctually be included, it's just an example
    }
}
```

Comment: javadocs are your friend, look at the available methods on the Random class.

Comment: ran1.next(). The Random() object itself is not the int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't assign a `Random` to an `int` -- you need to call [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-), passing a `int` that gives the range between `0` and that bound minus `1`.

```
a[i] = ran1.nextInt(10);  // 0-9 or substitute what you want for 10
```

Comment: so what do i insert in the () of nextInt

Comment: That depends on the intended range of random numbers you want to produce.  If you want numbers in the range 0-9, choose `10`.  If you want `0-99`, choose `100`.  If you want an arbitrary range, then please see [Generating random integers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java).

Comment: Closing the question is for questions with problems (unclear, off-topic, etc.).  That's not a good thing.  But instead you may mark exactly one answer in a question as "accepted", by clicking the check mark next to the answer that you think helped you the most.